# CSS Bootstrap navbar spacing trouble

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap to create a navbar, but I have a small problem. There is a small space underneath the navbar, which pushes the element underneath it. I'd like to remove the space while keeping the navbar intact. Is this possible without compromising the styles in my navbar? Any advice would be helpful.

I'd like to add something: What I'm referring to is Bootstrap's  adding space at the bottom. I've looked with firebug, but I'm having trouble changing the styles.

Comment: JaPerk, you'll get better/quicker responses if you share a jsfiddle for such questions.

Comment: @PerfectDark he is talking about the margin-bottom

Comment: @JaPerk did the solution I provided helped ya resolved the issue ? let me know if ya need more help in this regard

Answer (score 1):

Remove the default margin of navbar  at line 4290 of bootstrap.css i.e

```
.navbar {
   *position: relative;
   *z-index: 2;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
  overflow: visible;
  }
```

You can do the following to override it :

```
.navbar {
         margin-bottom:2px; or any thing you like 
        }
```